# Can not clear rocks in dragonvale

Tags: dragonvale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I clear rocks on dragonvale?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83030/why-cant-i-clear-rocks-on-dragonvale)

I am stuck on level six on dragonvale, the spade is greyed out, the market is greyed out and I have plenty of gold to clear the rocks. I have seen other questions on here relating to the same problem, but no true answers given...

Comment: Welcome to Arqade Laura.  As there are other questions on the site that relate to this issue, we prefer to have just one of them open (or active) so that when an answer is discovered, it is consolidated in one place.  As such, this question will be closed as a duplicate of the other.  However, you can favorite that question (using the star under the downvote button) and you will be informed when answers appear.

Comment: Also, I notice that someone asked for a screenshot on the other question - if you have a screenshot of the issue, feel free to suggest an edit on the other question and add the screenshot in.  Someone will approve it and that may help with an answer.